# ssh tunnel from azure bastion hosts

Tags: azure, ssh, devops

Is it possible to do ssh tunneling (SSH port forwarding) from azure bastion host?

Like we do normally from a jump box:

```
ssh -i path/to/private_key -L 127.0.0.1:FORWARD_PORT:VM_IP:APPLICATION_PORT user@jumphost.net


ssh -i path/to/private_key -L 127.0.0.1:8080:10.0.0.1:8080 user@jumphost.net
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need *port* fowarding? Your use case can perfectly use TCP forwarding like so, with the following SSH config.

```
Host JumpHost1
    Hostname jumphost1.net
    User user_jh1

Host JumpHost2
    Hostname jumphost2.net
    User user_jh2
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p JumpHost1

Host AppBox
    Hostname appbox_behind_firewall.net
    User app_user
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p JumpHost2
```

Then you can easily do `ssh AppBox` without issue. You'll need to have your local public key authenticated to each jumphost and the appbox. Which you should be able to easily do with `ssh-copy-id` if you are doing this with *OpenSSH*

Comment: Have you ever try this approach with azure bastion host?